# updating string array inside a function

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc, c99

I am trying to pass an array of strings with a new string to a function and inside this function I want to add this string to the array and reset the string. I seem to be unable to make it work inside the function, yet without one it works

```
int main(void)
{
    const char* text = "hello world";
    int text_length = strlen(text);

    char* words[text_length];
    char word[text_length];

    int length = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < text_length; ++i) {
        if (isspace(text[i])) {
            words[length] = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
            strcpy(words[length++], word);
            memset(word, 0, sizeof(word));
            k = 0;
        }

        //...
        //... adding chars to the word
        word[k++]= text[i];
    }
}
```

this works just fine, and this does not:

```
void add_word(char* words[], char* word, int* words_length, int* word_cursor)
{
    words[*words_length] = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
    strcpy(words[*words_length++], word);
    memset(word, 0, sizeof(word));
    *word_cursor = 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char* text = "hello world";
    int text_length = strlen(text);

    char* words[text_length];
    char word[text_length];

    int length = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < text_length; ++i) {
        if (isspace(text[i])) {
            add_word(words, word, &length, &k);
        }
        //...
        //... adding chars to the word
        word[k++]= text[i];
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Please try to create an [mcve] to show us, which include all variable definitions and how they are initialized. A perfect example would be one where we could copy-paste it and replicate your exact problem (and not get any unrelated errors).

Comment: By the way, in the `add_word` function `sizeof(word)` won't work (at least not the way you intend it to work).

Comment: sorry, I have updated my examples with all the lacking data.

Comment: In the function `add_word`, `word` is a pointer, not an array, so `sizeof(word)` is just the size of a pointer, not the length of the array.

Comment: `isspace(text[i])` is potentially broken. You need `isspace((unsigned char)text[i])`, otherwise the behavior of `isspace` with negative chars is not defined.

Comment: @Some programmer dude what would be the proper way to do it then?

Comment: @hvertous "this works just fine" - What does work fine?! The presented code does not make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My ***guess*** is that it doesn't work because you don't add the null-terminator properly in the `word` array.

In the second example you have just copy-pasted the code from the first working code, and forgot to change one crucial bit:

```
memset(word, 0, sizeof(word));
```

In the function `add_word` the variable `word` is a *pointer*, and `sizeof(word)` returns the size of the pointer itself and not what it points to.

The best solution to make sure that the string in `word` is always null-terminated is to actually and explicitly add the terminator at the place needed when you want to treat it as a string:

```
if (isspace(text[i])) {
    word[k] = '\0';  // Add null-terminator
    add_word(words, word, &length, &k);
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works. I removed memset inside the function and added a null-terminator to a word string. It now works well. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behavior with

```
void add_word(char* words[], char* word, int* words_length, int* word_cursor) {
   strcpy(words[*words_length++], word);
```

As, `word` does not contain space to hold `null` char.

```
const char* text = "hello world";
int text_length = strlen(text);
char word[text_length];
```

Should be

```
char word[text_length+1];
```

and

```
  …
    if (isspace(text[i])) {
        word[k]= '\0';   //Null terminate the string
        add_word(words, word, &length, &k);
    }
```

Comment: I did need actually to null-terminate my string with '\0', but I also had a memset problem inside my `add_words` so I will mark Some programmer dude's answer as correct one, but thanks anyways.